# How to read PDF with line numbers in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pdf

Hi I am trying to read pdf document along with line numbers.

[image: PDF]

In the above image I have showed PDF. In pdf file each line has line number. I want to save in the database like

```
Line Number  Content
1            It is agreed on the date shown in Box 2 between the party named in Box 3 as
```

when I read the document everything comes as text but how can I identify the line numbers and contents separately? because in content also number may appear so number logic doesnt help in identifying the line number. Is there anyway identify line numbers? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which library are you using to read the data from the PDF? I made an example using [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp), you can refer to it.

In the process of reading data line by line, use regular expressions to get the last line number of the string, and use the `TrimEnd()` method to remove it:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test.pdf");
    int intPageNum = reader.NumberOfPages;
    string[] words;
    string line;
    string text;
    PdfModel pdfModel = new PdfModel();

    for (int i = 1; i <= intPageNum; i++)
    {
        text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());

        words = text.Split('\n');
        for (int j = 0, len = words.Length; j < len; j++)
        {
            line = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(words[j]));
            var x = Regex.Match(line, @"([0-9]+)[^0-9]*$");
            if (x.Success && x.Groups.Count > 0)
            {
                var foundNumber = x.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value;
                line = line.Trim().TrimEnd(foundNumber.ToCharArray());
                pdfModel.Line = int.Parse(foundNumber);
                pdfModel.Content = line;
                _context.PdfModel.Add(pdfModel);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Test Result:

My PDF:

[image]

My Database:
[image]